# Acess a function in an Object

Tags: javascript, object

i try to access this function in my Object with the console.log but i don't really understand why i can't access it!
I'm beginning Javascript but i'm really stuck with accessing functions in Object.

Thanks for the help

```js
const hotel = {
    name: "Grand Hotel",
    location: "Stockholm",
    pricePerNight: 2200,
    roomBooked: 23,
    totalRoom: 223, 
    roomAvailable: function(){
        return this.totalRoom - this.roomBooked;
        
    }   
    };
    hotel.roomAvailable();
    console.log(hotel.roomAvailable);
```

Comment: First you call the function but ignore the return value, then you log the function itself but without calling it. Did you mean `console.log(hotel.roomAvailable());`?

Answer (score 2):

You're just missing the parentheses in the log function:

```
hotel.roomAvailable()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! i feel dumb haha

Answer (score 0):

You are already invoking the function which will return the value. Just log the return value instead.

In your code you are just logging the definition of the function but not really invoking it.

```js
const hotel = {
  name: "Grand Hotel",
  location: "Stockholm",
  pricePerNight: 2200,
  roomBooked: 23,
  totalRoom: 223,
  roomAvailable: function() {
    return this.totalRoom - this.roomBooked;

  }
};

var isRoomAvailable = hotel.roomAvailable();
console.log(isRoomAvailable);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```js
const hotel = {
    name: "Grand Hotel",
    location: "Stockholm",
    pricePerNight: 2200,
    roomBooked: 23,
    totalRoom: 223, 
    roomAvailable: function(){
        return this.totalRoom - this.roomBooked;
        
    }   
    };
  
    console.log(hotel.roomAvailable());
```